# Java Mail() with DB while loop

Tags: java

Is any way I can apply this loop without connect and disconnect to mail services? The loop is working fine for 2 or 5 people, but when is going to be 100 people is going take to long to send all the message. take around 3 sec on each loop.

```
     while(rs.next()){
     items = rs.getString("email");          



    try {

        Properties mail = new Properties();
        mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "cuatrocuadrado@gmail.com" );
        mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


         session=Session.getDefaultInstance(mail);
       message= new MimeMessage(session);
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("cuatrocuadrado@gmail.com"));
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(items));
        //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress());
        message.setSubject(Email.tSubject.getText());
        message.setText(Email.areaEmail.getText());

         Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect("cuatrocuadrado@gmail.com","*********");

        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        t.close();

        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
    }
} }  catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SendEmail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Success");
```

Comment: you want to send the same mail to different users.??

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far? (I see you have some working code, what have you tried to move towards a better solution?)

Comment: Could you move the connection construction stuff (session, properties, etc) that are common outside the loop, then just build each message and send it in the loop?  Even better might be to create a collection of messages, build all the messages up-front and put them in the collection, then open the connection, loop the collection (send each mail message), then close the connection after the loop.

Comment: Why not just store the email addresses you are trying to send to in an intermediate collection, close your database op, then connect to your mail server once, and loop through the intermediate collection to create and send mail messages?

Comment: Yes, is the same email for everyone who subscribe. 2)I was trying to add the while loop after TRY{ and the variable not work. ( so I remove the second TRY{ ) 3) Connection moving around, that is the answer, my mind was block. 4)I not have mail server I using Google like mail server :P .

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you.

**Fetch the email value from resultset and dynamically add it into array.**

```
String[] to = {"test1@gmail.com","test2@gmail.com","test3@gmail.com","test4@gmail.com"};
InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];
for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
{
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
}
msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this but you will again face another problem ... if you dont have a NS entry of your server gmail won't allow you to send to multiple recipients. if you do have amazon or other cloud services you could use them but they charge :P

```
try {

    Properties mail = new Properties();
    mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "cuatrocuadrado@gmail.com" );
    mail.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


    session=Session.getDefaultInstance(mail);
    message= new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("cuatrocuadrado@gmail.com"));

    ArrayList<InternetAddress> many = new ArrayList<InternetAddress>();
    while(rs.next()){
        many.add(new InternetAddress(rs.getString("email")));    
    }
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, many.toArray(new InternetAddress[many.length]));
    //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress());
    message.setSubject(Email.tSubject.getText());
    message.setText(Email.areaEmail.getText());

    Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
    t.connect("cuatrocuadrado@gmail.com","*********");

    t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

    t.close();

}catch (MessagingException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
}catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SendEmail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: DarthCoder After I think deeper I was able of do the loop. My issue was connecting and dropping so i put the connection out of the loop and the loop send message one by one and not in bulk or multiple recipient.

Comment: session=Session.getDefaultInstance(mail);
        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect("cuatrocuadrado@gmail.com","**********");

        while(rs.next()){
     items = rs.getString("email");